# How to read() the output from a child process while it's still running

Tags: c, parent-child, wait

Im trying to read the output from a child process using read().

my child process is a text based RPG game. My parent is a AI solver, which will read the output of quester, and give it input.

I need to read the output of my child, while my child process is waiting for input via a prompt >

Ive created my pipes using an implimentation of popen2(), a double ended pipe

problem: every time I try to read my child pipe, I get an infinite loop. This is because Im trying to read() while my child is waiting for input via its prompt '>'.

My source code it below

here are some things to note:

*if I comment out my call to kill(), I STILL get stuck in an infinite loop when I call read().

My idea, in theory, is:

*child gives me output -> child SIGSTOP -> process the output -> give my child input -> child SIGCONT -> loop

```
#define _POSIX_SOURCE
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <signal.h>

/**
 * popen2 and struct popen2 
 * taken from http://emergent.unpythonic.net/01108826729
 * Website Copyright © 2004-2014 Jeff Epler
 */

char *const *parmList;
struct popen2
{
    pid_t child_pid;
    int   from_child, to_child;
};

int popen2(char * const argv, struct popen2 *childinfo)
{
    pid_t p;
    int pipe_stdin[2], pipe_stdout[2];

    if(pipe(pipe_stdin)) return -1;
    if(pipe(pipe_stdout)) return -1;

    p = fork();
    if(p < 0) return p; /* Fork failed */
    if(p == 0) { /* child */
        close(pipe_stdin[1]);
        dup2(pipe_stdin[0], 0);
        close(pipe_stdout[0]);
        dup2(pipe_stdout[1], 1);
        execv( "./quester", parmList );
        perror( "execl" ); exit(99);
    }
    childinfo->child_pid = p;
    childinfo->to_child = pipe_stdin[1];
    childinfo->from_child = pipe_stdout[0];
    return 0;
}

void ai_go (char * buffer, size_t count)
{


}

int main ( int argc, char * const argv[] )
{
  struct popen2* childinfo = calloc( 1, sizeof( struct popen2 ) );
  parmList = argv;
  popen2( *argv, childinfo );

  kill( childinfo->child_pid, SIGSTOP );

  char * buffer = calloc ( 256, sizeof ( char ) );

  read ( childinfo -> from_child, buffer, 100 );


}
```

Comment: Are you sure it's an infinite loop, and not, say, a blocking `read()` that never unblocks because the writer is `SIGSTOP`ed?

Comment: Is the child using `stdio` to write its output? By default, `stdio` will buffer the output if it's going to a pipe. You can easily get into a deadlock, because the child won't fill up its buffer until you send more input, but you won't send input until you read the output, which is still buffered.

Comment: thats exactly my problem. The instructions say for parents to read the childs output (output is from stdio) which is waiting for input (because it's a text based game) and then give input to child, which will in turn give the parent more output, which is basically just a loop until child is executed fully ( win or lose )